# Android build APK release

Tags: android, build.gradle, apk

I am trying to build release APK but no luck i am getting error

[image: Error:]

Solution is to turn off offline mode and i did as you can see on image bellow

[image]

But i still have this error. What is the problem?

Comment: can you check here please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45839593/gradle-build-lintvitalrelease-nullpointerexception ?

Comment: This was solution. I added line "checkReleaseBuilds false". Thanks for help

Comment: you are welcome :) Good Luck :D

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think that your network is down.
You need to have Gradle tools and Gradle version running in harmony. So correct your compilation options with project structure.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit in detail? How do i check if it's not in harmony?